# My PHP script stops suddenly without showing errors

Tags: php

I'm making a script that does the same thing as weleakinfo.com: you enter an email and the script searches it in leaked databases.

I've uploaded all the txt files (named from 1.txt to 230.txt) and they are all the same: each file is in the format email:password.

At first, I used file() to read the lines in the files, but I got memory errors, so now I used fscanf() (I was told that way was a better one).

Now I get no errors but the script stops searching when around 40 seconds have passed.

I have set the max_execution_time to "infinite" (0), but it still stops working at 40 seconds of having started.

The code is the following, I don't find the error:

```
$email = $_POST["email"];

if ($email != '') {

      for ($i = 1; $i < 231; $i++) {                // a loop to open all the files
        $filename = $i.'.txt';
        $file = fopen($filename,'r');
        $combo = fscanf($file,"%[^'\n']");

        while($combo){
          $combo = (fscanf($file,"%[^'\n']"))[0];   // read a line (email:password)
          $comboemail = (explode(':',$combo))[0];   // read only the email
          if ($comboemail == $email) {     
            echo $combo.'<br/>';
            break 2;
          }
        }
        fclose($file);
        echo 'searched in file: '.$filename.'<br/>';
      }
    }
```

Comment: Try set_time_limit(500); (The default time limit is 30 seconds)

Comment: If you believe that you are getting an error somewhere, add these two lines at the top of your script: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` ... and: `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` ... and see if you get any error-related output.

Comment: Run a `if (file_exists($filename)) { etc... }` first before you open it

Comment: Try using a database to store your data. All other suggestions are stupid.

Comment: That's what I'm going to do, Salman, but I would like to know where is the problem. I've already tried with set_time_limit, error_reporting...

Comment: @kvothe you are looping over 231 files and some of them are 700MB+ in size or contain 1million+ records, right? Now (i) loading such a file all at once in memory will cause memory limit exhausted error (ii) processing tens of millions of records one by one will lead you to time limit exceed error. You ***can*** `set_time_limit(0)` but the web server also has its own timeout setting for rogue scripts. It seems like your webserver is configured with a time limit of 40 seconds and it _kills_ the PHP script after it. That is probably why PHP is not able to complain about or log any errors.